# How can I plot "Arrival time" in my Shiny app? There are duplicates of each "Id" and "Arrival time"

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have chosen to use a long dataset for the plot. The variable "Arrival Time" means when somebody arrives at work. The variable "Mode" means the preferred mode of transport. However, the preferred mode of transport can be more than one. For example, some participants have chosen "Yes" to both "Car" and "Bicycle".

I need to plot the "Arrival time", which should be unique for every value of "Id".

I need to be able to filter the different modes of transport in my `sidebarPanel`.

I need to be able to choose all modes of transport

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(do)
library(shinyWidgets)

#1. READ DATA FROM EXCEL
Survey <- read_excel("~/EIGSI/Project/Work files for R studio/06_Participant.xlsx")


#2.SUBSET DATA
Data <- subset(Survey, select = c(1,3,5:14))

colnames(Data) <- c(
  'Id',
  'Arrival time',
  'On foot',
  'Bicycle',
  'Bicycle (Yélo)',
  'Motorcycle/scooter',
  'Scooter (trotinette)',
  'Bus',
  'Train',
  'Car',
  'Carpool',
  'Car (Yélo)'
)

#3.GATHER DATA FOR LONG TABLE
Data <- Data %>% 
  gather(key = "Mode",
         value = "Answer",
         -Id, -`Arrival time`)



#4. OPTIONAL: ORDER THE X-AXIS OF THE PLOT
Data$`Arrival time` = ordered(Data$`Arrival time`, levels = c(
  "before 7h00",
  "7h00 - 7h30",
  "7h30 - 8h00",
  "8h00 - 8h30",
  "8h30 - 9h00",
  "9h00 - 9h30",
  "after 9h30"
  
))


#5. MAKE VECTOR OF CHOICES
a <- c(unique(Data$Mode))


#6. CONFIGURE THE SHINY APPLICATION
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Arrival times"),  # Add a title panel
  sidebarLayout(  
    position = "right",
    
    sidebarPanel(h3("Inputs for histogram"),
                 pickerInput("Mode", "Select mode", choices = a, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T),
                 br()
    ),
    
    
    # Inside the sidebarLayout, add a sidebarPanel
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myhist")
      
    )  
  )
)

# server.R ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$myhist <- renderPlot({
    
    observe({
      print(input$Mode) #ENABLES ME TO CHOOSE ALL VARIABLES
    })

    
  Data %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=`Arrival time`))+
      geom_histogram(stat = "count", data = Data[Data$Mode==input$Mode ,])
    
  })
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is an example of the dataset called `Data`, I show it using the `dput()` function:

```
     structure(list(Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), `Arrival time` = structure(c(3L, 
6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("before 7h00", 
"7h00 - 7h30", "7h30 - 8h00", "8h00 - 8h30", "8h30 - 9h00", "9h00 - 9h30", 
"after 9h30"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Mode = c("On foot", 
"On foot", "On foot", "On foot", "Scooter (trotinette)", "Scooter (trotinette)", 
"Scooter (trotinette)", "Scooter (trotinette)", "Carpool", "Carpool", 
"Carpool", "Carpool"), Answer = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 9157L, 9158L, 9159L, 9160L, 18313L, 18314L, 18315L, 
18316L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @Simen!  Please post a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the data you read in from excel to help with your question

Comment: Hello @MattO. I tried to use the dput() function for this, but the table becomes too large for Stack Overflow. How can I write code in the comment section?

Comment: Just a small sample of the data will probably be enough @Simen

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have now posted a sample of the data using dput function.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but usually not a good idea to put an `observe()` within a `renderPlot()` (or any other `reactive()`)

Comment: @HubertL . My main goal is to plot the "Arrival time" in a histogram AND be able to filter the different values of "Mode" in a shiny app. However, my problem is to get the plot itself correct. For example, participant with Id number 2 have chosen both "Bicycle" and "Car", however, their "Arrival time" is the same. Having two modes of transport for Id 1 number 1 will then have two rows with "Arrival time" in the dataset: One row for Bicycle and one for Car.  Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Try making your app in small steps  : first get the numbers correct ( group by id could help you remove duplicates), then make the plot, then put that in shiny. Debugging several issues at the same time in shiny is very difficult

Answer (score 0):

So just to clarify: What you want to do is first select the rows where the mode is one of the chosen modes and the answer is yes, and then plot the arrival times of those rows.

First, you can subset the dataset so it's only the modes you want and the answers "Yes". Now you have only the rows you want, but like you pointed out, some rows are duplicated.

Next, you drop the Mode and Answer columns and set Data to unique(Data). Dropping those two columns means you only have the ID and Arrival Time columns, and running the unique() will drop the duplicate rows and leave you with one row per ID (assuming each ID only has one arrival time).

One note, in your filter, you do this: data = Data[Data$Mode==input$Mode

This is not what you want because of two reasons:

1. It will take all rows that have the input Mode, even if the answer is No. You want to add an additional filter that the answer has to be Yes.
2. It will not work with multiple selections. Instead of ==, use %in%. This way, even if there are multiple selections, the filter will still work.

Comment: You write that I should drop Mode and answer from the set Data. When this is done, how should I specify the input for Mode in the plot? I ask because you suggest I drop Mode earlier.

Comment: No, first you subset the dataset to only consider the Mode you want, then you drop Mode. You will need to redo these two steps every time a new Mode is selected. As such, store the main dataset in a reactive, then call that and subset every time your plot is refreshed. That way, your main dataset is not touched and you can return to it every time you change selections.